# admob Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView

Tags: android, sdk, admob

I have app that runs admob ads in it. Recently I switched to new admob SDK (6.3.1) and set mediation key instead of standard admob key. I didn't change anything in code except of key. Now I've received this error through developer console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.WebBrowser}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.mycompany.myapp.AdHandler.loadAdmobAd(AdHandler.java:61)
at com.mycompany.myapp.AdHandler.loadAd(AdHandler.java:28)
at com.mycompany.myapp.WebBrowser.onCreate(WebBrowser.java:173)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Optimized data directory /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.mycompany.myapp/cache is not owned by the current user. Shared storage cannot protect your application from code injection attacks.
at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadDex(DexFile.java:149)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:261)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:229)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:96)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:52)
at dalvik.system.DexClassLoader.<init>(DexClassLoader.java:57)
at com.google.ads.ak.f(SourceFile:354)
at com.google.ads.ak.b(SourceFile:95)
at com.google.ads.ak.a(SourceFile:69)
at com.google.ads.n.<init>(SourceFile:158)
at com.google.ads.internal.d.<init>(SourceFile:267)
at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:508)
at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:370)
at com.google.ads.AdView.<init>(SourceFile:125)
... 25 more
```

User leave me this message: Crashed when opening again

This is AdHandler class:

```
public class AdHandler {
    private Activity act;
    private AppClass appState;

    public AdHandler(Activity _act,AppClass _appState){
        act=_act;
        appState=_appState;
    }

    public void loadAd() {
        loadAdmobAd();
    }

    public void loadAdmobAd_() {
        //no ads!
        return;
    }

    public void loadAdmobAd() {
        AdView adView=(AdView) act.findViewById(R.id.vw_adview_admob);

        if(adView==null) {
            LinearLayout adBlock=(LinearLayout)act.findViewById(R.id.ad_block);
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) act.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.vw_admobcontainer, adBlock);
            adView = (AdView) v.findViewById(R.id.vw_adview_admob);
        }

        act.findViewById(R.id.vw_admobcontainer).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        act.findViewById(R.id.ad_block).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        AdRequest ar = new AdRequest();

        ar.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

        adView.loadAd(ar);

        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
                act.findViewById(R.id.ad_block).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(WebBrowser.class.isInstance(act)){
                    appState.browserAddLoaded=false;
                    ((WebBrowser)act).setAllWebBrowserButtons();
                }
            }

            public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
                if(WebBrowser.class.isInstance(act)){
                    appState.browserAddLoaded=true;

                    act.findViewById(R.id.ad_block).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    act.findViewById(R.id.ad_block).invalidate();
                    ((WebBrowser)act).setWebBrowserButtons();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is admob xml (vw_admobcontainer):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 
    android:id="@+id/vw_admobcontainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <!-- Admob - MEDIATION -->
    <com.google.ads.AdView

            android:id="@+id/vw_adview_admob"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="8xxxxxxxxxxx1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is admob container xml (ad_block):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 
    android:id="@+id/ad_block"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp" 
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is layout of activity that includes ad_block layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/sky"  >

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="1" >

    <WebView android:id="@+id/web_browser"  
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
               />  

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/web_browser_bussy" 
         android:layout_width="50dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         style="@style/android:Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         />

    </FrameLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/ad_block" />
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/web_browser_progress_bar" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="5dp"
         style="@style/android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
         android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
         />
    <include layout="@layout/web_browser_footer"  android:id="@+id/browser_footer" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Admob SDK is inside lib folder and ads working fine. I never succeed to create this error on my devices.

Can anyone tell me what is the issue?

Comment: What line is `com.mycompany.myapp.AdHandler.loadAdmobAd(AdHandler.java:61)`. Are you sure you're using the right layout file. I see you're referencing `R.id.ad_block` but I don't see that in XML anywhere.

Comment: I've just added 2 missing part of layout. Line 61 in adHandler is: `View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.vw_admobcontainer, adBlock);`. In onCreate of activity I have those two lines: `AdHandler adHandler=new AdHandler(this,appState);
        adHandler.loadAd();`

Comment: So it looks like an issue inflating the AdView from code. I'm not sure exactly why this is happening, but I don't understand why you need to inflate `vw_admobcontainer` from code this way. Why can't you combine the `ad_block` and `vw_admobcontainer` XML files, and let your `<include layout="@layout/ad_block"/>` call include the AdView in XML?

Comment: When I've started this project, there was no mediation so I created mediation manually. Then depending on current active ad network I was inflating layout from code that I need. Now I don't need that. So I will try to combine those 2 XML files into one layout file and remove inflating code. Thank you for all help.

Comment: Hi, I'm encountering a similar issue, since I'm creating the AdView in code: new AdView(..)  I can say it seems to have nothing to do with the xml layout.
This is the exception that is thrown by AdView in the init:
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Optimized data directory /data/data/.../cache is not owned by the current user. Shared storage cannot protect your application from code injection attacks." it's the same one you are receiving. It only happens randomly did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi Raanan, I joined those files together and removed inflation from code. I didn't have errors any more. I don't know will that help you.